# How can I visualize categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, data-visualization

I have two datasets like this (dots are random numbers):

```
  Category 1

    A B C D E F G H
  1 3 0 0 3 . . .
  2 2 0 0 2 . . . .
  3 0 2 4 2 . . . .
  4 1 1 5 2 . . . .
  5 0 . . . . . . .
  6 2 . . . . . . .
  7 3 . . . . . . .
  8 0 . . . . . . .


  Category 2

    A B C D E F G H
  1 1 0 0 1 . . . .
  2 1 0 0 1 . . . .
  3 1 2 1 2 . . . .
  4 0 1 5 0 . . . .
  5 0 . . . . . . .
  6 0 . . . . . . .
  7 3 . . . . . . .
  8 0 . . . . . . .
```

A-H = things that the respondent should rank

1-10 = the ranking

Ex. A is one time ranked on place 1, two times ranked on place 2 and zero times ranked on place 3 etc.

I have two different kind of people that filled in the survey (Category 1 & Category 2) so that's why there are two datasets with different kind of outcomes.
Now I want to visualize this in the best way possible, so that you can see things like Category 1 find A & D more important than Category 2. I work with python/pandas/matplotlib.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the columns `A B C D E F G H` into:
`A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1` for Dataset 1
`A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2` for Dataset 2

Then merge the datasets.

Comment: Already did that and now I want to make a visualization of it. I did a bar chart, with all different colors, but that didn't gave a clear overview. Do you have ideas?

Comment: Yes, sort the columns by name so you have A1 A2 B1 B2 close to each other, possibly paired.